# Как в postgres результат 10/3 привести к numeric(15,2)?

Tags: postgresql, cast

В результате запроса у меня получается 3.00.
Как мне получить 3.33?

```
SELECT
    CAST(10 / 3 AS NUMERIC(15,2))
```

Comment: 10.0 / 3 - вероятно поможет

Comment: работает SELECT
    CAST(10.0 / 3 AS NUMERIC(15,2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь важен порядок операций. `cast` применяется уже к результату выражения, тогда как константу 10 синтаксический парсер воспринимает как `integer` и 3 тоже `integer`, следовательно выбирается оператор целочисленного деления и результат его тоже `integer`. Нужно хотя бы один операнд указать как `numeric`, тогда второй будет приведён к `numeric` автоматически и будет использован оператор деления `numeric`

```
melkij=> select cast(10 as numeric) / 3;
      ?column?      
--------------------
 3.3333333333333333
(1 строка)

melkij=> select 10 / cast(3 as numeric);
      ?column?      
--------------------
 3.3333333333333333
(1 строка)
```